# CSS hover, focus and "unfocus"

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, menu

I am trying to make custom menu animation using bootstrap. I would like to have three stages. First when hovered, second when focused (menu icon pressed) and last when unfocused (menu icon pressed again).

menu:

```css
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .bar:nth-of-type(1) {
  display: block;
  width: 3em;
  margin: 0.3em;
  border: 0.1em solid white;
  transition-duration: 600ms;
}

#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .bar:nth-of-type(2) {
  display: block;
  width: 1em;
  margin-left: 2.7em;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  border: 0.1em solid white;
  transition-duration: 600ms;
}

#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .bar:nth-of-type(3) {
  display: block;
  width: 3em;
  margin: 0.3em;
  border: 0.1em solid white;
  transition-duration: 600ms;
  margin-right:0.5em;
}

CSS animation on hover:
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover .bar:nth-of-type(2) {
  margin-left: 1.4em;
}

CSS animation on focus:
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus .bar:nth-of-type(2) {
  margin-left: -0.1em;
}
```

```html
<nav id="custom-bootstrap-menu" class=" navbar navbar-default  navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
   <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle"   data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navHeaderCollapse">
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <span class="bar"></span>
   </button>
 </div>
</nav>
```

On hover second bar is moving to the middle from right, then when the menu is pressed, the bar moves to the left. My problem is that if you press the menu icon again nothing is happening (the bar is still on the left side) since it is being focused, so you have to press somewhere else to unfocus the menu and reset the process.

I would like the same thing to happen after you press the menu icon again, so to unfocus the icon if it is pressed for the second time (bar should move to the right side).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My solution involves adding an "onmouseenter" handler to clear the "focus" state of the button. You should add this event handler to the button in the onload but in it's simplest form, try this:

```
<script>
function losefocus(target) {
  target.blur();
}
</script>
<nav id="custom-bootstrap-menu" class=" navbar navbar-default  navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button id="mb" type="button" class="navbar-toggle"   data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navHeaderCollapse" onmouseenter="losefocus(this)">
                    <span class="bar"></span>
                    <span class="bar"></span>
                    <span class="bar"></span>
    </button>
  </div>
</nav>
```

If you want a toggling button, the current "hover" change is confusing. May I suggest you use something other than bar(2) moving to the centre to indicate hovering, so the focused/unfocused state of the button is always obvious. As an example:

```
 <script>
var isfocused = 0;
function toggle(target) {
  isfocused = (isfocused + 1) % 2;  
  if (isfocused) {
        target.focus(); 
  } else {
        target.blur(); 
  }    
}
</script>
<nav id="custom-bootstrap-menu" class=" navbar navbar-default  navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button id="mb" type="button" class="navbar-toggle"   data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navHeaderCollapse" onclick="toggle(this)" >
                    <span class="bar"></span>
                    <span class="bar"></span>
                    <span class="bar"></span>
    </button>
  </div>
</nav>
```

The :hover CSS changes to something like this

```
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover .bar:nth-of-type(2) {
 border: 0.1em solid black;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, although it works only partially. It clears the focus but only when you move the mouse away from the menu icon. In the situation, you press the menu icon first time and then the second time straight away, while the cursor is still on menu icon - nothing is happening.

Comment: So you want the button to toggle on and off with each click, meaning the vertical bar moves back to the right on the second click?

Comment: Note that in my modified answer, you now have a variable "isfocused" that you can easliy reference to determine the state of the button.

Comment: This is great. It works perfectly as I wish. On second click the bar moves back to the middle and it is fine by me. Thank you a lot.

Comment: Could you please explain this line for me: isfocused = (isfocused + 1) % 2; ? I wander how it works.

Comment: % id the modulus operator, giving the remainder when dividing  (isfocused + 1)  by 2. so it alternates between 0 and 1. It's a quick way of achieving this: if (isfocused==1) {isfocused = 0;} else {isfocused = 1;};

Comment: My pleasure @jacoboy. And I like your "animated" buttons - I'll try that approach myself. Very cool.

Comment: I am happy to hear that. Good luck!